# 1-phase induction hob connection

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, kitchens

G'day!

I would like to connect a Bosch induction hob ([PVS775FC5E](https://manuals.coolblue.nl/d4/bosch-pvs775fc5e.pdf)) to a dedicated circuit breaker (25A, 230V with no other load on it) at home (built 1998, Netherlands).

According to the hob manual, I can connect to 1-phase by using the bridge (see middle of the picture below), instead of the normal 2-phase connection.

If I **limit the maximum power** of the hob to 5500 W (which is settable via the control buttons), can I safely use the **1-phase connection**?

I understand that the CombiZone of the hob won't work at maximum possible power in this case.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What cable are you using? What is the cross section of the cable?

Comment: This seems to be what the slightly cryptic instructions suggest.  Do NL regulations permit the planning and installation of a circuit that will routinely run at 96% capacity?

Comment: @Paul there should be a sticker on the device, that indicates the allowed breaker capacity

Comment: You should really talk to their support. Basing it on our Asko. It is separated into three phases, each powering different elements/zones.,  I would suggest that you only connect one pair, not both. To me, that would be the safest option.  That is wire as if its 2 or 3 phase, but only connect one set

Comment: Hi @Martin cable: 2.5 sqmm, solid copper. Don't have yet the device (so no breaker information), trying to figure out if I need to upgrade to 3-phase connection.

Comment: @jay613 I could reduce the power setting further to be at 80% of capacity of the circuit breaker

Comment: @Martin because commercially available hobs don't work of 400V, so I'm curious how this could be "the first".  "Three-phase" connection is either first, or last drawing, depending on neutral configuration. In Paul's case, I would bet on first.

Comment: @jakuboz not true. My current induction hub, and the previous one allows a 3phase connection. Same as the other ones I helped connect. And the shown drawing never presents 3 phases, always 2..

Comment: @Martin: I confirm that it is advertised as a 2-phase (Perilex plug, max 6900 W) hob. However the installation manual shows that 1-phase connection is also possible

Comment: @Paul Yes, the single phase connection is possible. But then you are limited on the allowable load for a single 2.5mm². For 16A that's 3.7KW, for 20A: 4.6KW.

Answer (score 0):

2.5mm² seems to be at the limit for 25A. We Italians allow max. 16A for 2.5mm². You need to consult your local electrical code to verify the exact limit.

Given the possibility, I'd upgrade to an 3-phase connection, but use only two phases and use the third one for the oven. (2 x 230V x 16A = 7.2KW)

Many hubs, not necessarily yours, have an convenient second bridged neutral, and an unlabeled non-connected terminal (for the third phase) to ease attaching the oven to the hub. I suspect that's the case in yours, but need measurements to verify.

Given the magic of the 3phase phase shift you won't overload the neutral, event with 3 active hots.

Answer (score 0):

Answer part: If you limit it to 5500W- my answer is **no**.
What matters is not only cable cross-section, but also how it is mounted (air/on-wall, on-wall duct, in-wall duct, in-wall/ground) because cables need to keep themselves sufficiently cool during operation.
For 2.5sqmm copper, allowable loads are: for air- 29A, on-wall duct- 25A, in-wall duct- 21A. This might of course differ from country to country.
For safety reason- I'd take the worst possible case of 21A allowance.
Which corresponds to 4830W of load.

Recommendation part:
For my liking 25A breaker for 2.5sqmm conductor is too big, I'd personally not go for anything bigger than 20A (depends also on breaker time characteristics).
What you can do is: go three-phase / change conductor size to 4sqmm, and leave the 25A breaker (you will have 6400W available) / leave 2.5sqmm conductor, change breaker to 20A, limit power to 4500W.

Answer (score 0):

**20A:** I think that in NL a 2.5mm wire needs a 20A breaker, or 30A if it's on a ring.  I'm way beyond my knowledge there, you should ask an electrician or look that up in Dutch on local forums.  If it's a direct run to the breaker panel, and hence 20A, you're allowed 4600W so need to configure your hob for 4500W, the next available setting.

**Make it orange:** There are a bunch of things you need to validate .... Is 20A correct?  If so are you allowed to plan and install appliances that will run near 100% capacity continuously or do you need to reduce the load further?   Are you allowed to intentionally install an appliance on a breaker that relies on software settings to avoid overloading the wire if the breaker fails?   You need a *local* electrician to answer these questions.   I haven't seen people with deep knowledge of European regulations answer questions here.  Perhaps you could introduce your electrician to this site?

**Just because you can:** Let's imagine it's all allowed, should you?  If you enjoy cooking or if you entertain much, dumbing down your hob to half its actual capacity would be, for me, a frustration.  If it's not crazy expensive I'd upgrade the electrical service to the hob.  If your home is single phase run a second cable with its own neutral and wire as in the third diagram.

**Weird:** I would want to know what algorithm the hob uses to limit power if it needs to.     If you're cooking something on element A and you turn on element B and the hob needs to manage down the power, does it reduce element A, possibly ruining whatever is cooking there?   Or does it just ALWAYS reduce the max power of every element ... so that even if you only want to use one element at max power, you cannot?